# SQL Server datetimeoffset and for json auto changing datetimeoffset to datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I am selecting a record from a table that has multiple `datetimeoffet` columns, when I add the for json auto it converts it from

```
2017-06-21 08:12:16.1430000 +00:00
```

to

```
2017-06-21T08:12:16.1430000Z
```

This is my code:

```
select LastUpdateTimestamp 
from table
where id = 1
for json auto
```

which produces this output:

```
[{"LastUpdateTimestamp":"2017-06-21T08:12:16.1430000Z"}]
```

How can I keep it in the format without it being converted, or how can I convert it in C# back to that format? I am doing a lot of dynamic work and I can't rely on all dates to fit a certain format.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What SQL Server version and service pack are you using?

Comment: column is datatimeoffset(7) put 2017-06-21T08:12:16.1430000Z as the value in the column then run select LastUpdateTimestamp from table for json auto and it converts it to a json datatime. That is the problem

Answer (score 1):

[There is no JSON datetime data type nor standard for string formats for datetime data in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format). The underlying SQL Server `datetimeoffset(7)` data type is a 10-byte binary structure with no notion of format so it cannot be represented in a JSON string without conversion.

SQL Server returns ISO 8601 formatted strings by default with `JSON AUTO`. The problem you are experiencing is that the '+00:00' is suppressed with UTC; the offset is included only when the UTC offset is non-zero.

You can use the `FORMAT` T-SQL function to control the string format if the JSON AUTO defaults are not sufficient:

```
FORMAT(LastUpdateTimestamp,'O') AS LastUpdateTimestamp
```

Comment: The part that makes using the format difficult or i would have done it already is i am grabbing * on the result as it is running a bit of code dynamically over multiple tables. I can build out some code to break the * up into actual column names and if its datatimeoffset run the format

Answer (score -1):

```
select DATE_FORMAT
      (LastUpdateTimestamp,'%d %M %Y')
        from table where id = 1
```

Use MySQL DATE_FORMAT function

Comment: I just want the raw value to come over not converted in the for json.

Comment: or a way to convert it back without specifying a format

Comment: Why suggest a MySQL function as an answer to a Microsoft SQL Server Question?